# how to apply non-linear least square

Tags: estimation, least-squares

I'm trying to implement the example of estimating an angle between a target $\textbf{x}$ and a sensor $x_{p}$. I'm using the example in this [book](http://ca.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-047141655X.html). There are three available measurements of the angle in radian as follows

$$
z = 
\begin{bmatrix}
z(1) \\
z(2) \\
z(3) 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\textbf{h}(\textbf{x}, x_{p}) + w
$$

where $\textbf{x} = [x \ y]$ is the position of the target, $x_{p} = [x_{px} \ x_{py}]$ is the position of the sensor and $w$ is the noise. The actual function of this sensor is

$$
\textbf{h}(\textbf{x}, x_{p}) = tan^{-1} \frac{y - x_{py}}{x - x_{px}}
$$

The linearized version of $\textbf{h}(.)$ is provided through Jacobian $J$ as follows

$$
J = \frac{\partial h(\textbf{x},x_{p})}{\partial \textbf{x}}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial h(\textbf{x},x_{p_{1}})}{\partial x} &
\frac{\partial h(\textbf{x},x_{p_{1}})}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial h(\textbf{x},x_{p_{2}})}{\partial x} &
\frac{\partial h(\textbf{x},x_{p_{2}})}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial h(\textbf{x},x_{p_{3}})}{\partial x} &
\frac{\partial h(\textbf{x},x_{p_{3}})}{\partial y} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

assuming the variance of the noise is same, the formula of Least Square is

$$
\hat{x} = (J^{T}J)^{-1} J^{T} z
$$

In my simulation,

```
z =
    0.7548
    0.9402
    2.2379
J =
   -0.0621    0.0552
   -0.0552    0.0621
    0.2500    0.2500
xbar =  <--- wrong
   -2.7493
   11.7078
```

As you can see $\hat{x}$ is not only wrong, but its dimension is weird. I'm expecting it to be `3x1` but I'm getting `2x1`

---

Edited:
The following picture illustrates the problem.

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to discern what you're doing. First, what is the difference between $\mathbf{x}$ and $x_p$: specifically, which one of these is your set of data points and which is the parameter? Next, why is the dimension wrong: both your data and parameters are 2x1, so why do you expect 3x1?

Comment: @AlexR. I've included the picture. I'm expecting the result to be `3x1` since I have three different observations of different sensors. I'm expecting the filter to estimate each observation. Unless I misunderstand the problem. For one sensor of multiple observations, I should get one estimated value of the angle which minimizes the squared error.

Comment: This is AOA (Angle Of Arrival), or DOA (Direction Of Arrival), in 2D right? Anyway, your expectation is wrong: the result is $2\times1$, since you are estimating the $[x \ y]$ position of the target. If you have one sensor with multiple obversations, this information is used to "kill" (reduce) the noise. If you have $N$ sensors with multiple observations, the information is "combined" (in the Least-Square sense) with the goal to minimize the sum of the squared residuals. If you do simple matrix dimensional checking, you get $2\times1$. If you want more details, I can write an answer.

Comment: @PseudoRandom, I'm estimating the angle, why would I get the position of the target? I know that the ultimate goal is to determine the location of the target, but to do so I need the best estimated angle. Given the best estimated angle and the position of the sensor, I can estimate the position of the target. I'm stuck with how to use Least Square for nonlinear systems to acquire the best estimated parameter.

Comment: "I'm estimating the angle" is, strictly speaking, wrong. The angles, which you grouped in the vector $\mathbf{z}$ (bold for vectors), are your observables. And you can't estimate observables. What you are talking about ("given the best estimated angle [...]") is called triangulation and it is another topic entirely. Just look at the Jacobian matrix: you are deriving w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, i.e. the target coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let us refresh some concepts of LS (Least Squares) estimation. Let $K$ be a positive integer and let $\mathbf{1}_K = [1 \ 1 \ \cdots \ 1]^T \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times 1}$ be an all-ones vector ($K$-dimensional), where $^T$ denotes transpose. Consider a single sensor doing $K$ (noisy) obversations of the same angle, $\phi$. Then, denoting with $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times 1}$ the observables of the true angle $\phi$, you have that
$$
\mathbf{y} = \phi \mathbf{1}_K + \mathbf{w}, \quad \mathbf{w} \sim (\mathbf{0}, \ \sigma^2 \mathbf{I}_K)
$$
where $\mathbf{I}_K$ is the $K \times K$ identity matrix and $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times 1}$ is a noisy term (for which we do not care about its specific distribution), but we do suppose that it is zero mean, uncorrelated and with the same variance. With the only exception of the zero-mean hypothesis, the other hypothesis, for LS, are not crucial (just for simplicity). The "best" (in the LS-sense) estimate of the angle $\phi$ is given by
$$
(*) \quad \hat{\phi}_{LS} = (\mathbf{1}_K^T \mathbf{1}_K)^{-1} \mathbf{1}_K^T \mathbf{y}
$$
Under the additional hypothesis that $\mathbf{w} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \sigma^2 \mathbf{I}_K)$, the above $(*)$ is also the ML (*Maximum Likelihood*) estimate of $\phi$. Equation $(*)$ is the famous *sample mean* estimator, since it can be rewritten as
$$
\hat{\phi} = \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^K y_k
$$
where $y_k$ is the $k$-th component of vector $\mathbf{y}$. The *sample mean* can be used even if you have an unknown covariance matrix $\mathbf{C}$: only the zero-mean hypothesis (which is the typical scenario with AOA, *Angle Of Arrival*) has relevance (if the mean is nonzero, but known, you can subtract it and rewrite the problem with zero-mean noise; if the mean is nonzero and unknown, not much can be done, the results will be biased). If you have $N$ sensors, then the target position can be estimated using *triangulation*.

Now, this is **not** the case. The formula which uses the Jacobian matrix is actually estimating *directly* the target position: however, some things must be made clear.

In vector $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1}$, in order for what you wrote to make sense, you should actually collect the $N$ estimated angles $\hat{\phi}_n$, with $n=1,\dots, N$. Each angle estimate is a sample mean done on $K$ observations of the same angle, i.e.,
$$
\mathbf{y}_n = \phi_n \mathbf{1}_K + \mathbf{w}_n, \quad n=1,\dots,N
$$
and then, letting $\mathbf{z} \triangleq [\hat{\phi}_1 \ \hat{\phi_2} \cdots \hat{\phi}_N]^T \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1}$, it makes sense to say that
$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}} = (\mathbf{J}^T \mathbf{J})^{-1} \mathbf{J}^T \mathbf{z}
$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{x}} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1}$ is the estimated target position (and $\mathbf{J} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 2}$ the Jacobian matrix, obviously). Simple dimensional checking proves that $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ is a $2 \times 1$ vector (since the problem is in 2D).

What about errors? Errors come from a combination of a variety of factors. First of all, noise variance, $\sigma^2$, is indeed a limiting factor on performances: the impact of $\sigma^2$ can be reduced by increasing $K$ (if possible, this is always a good idea). Secondly, the LS procedure is using only the first-derivative of the function (of the whole Taylor series) and thus it is an approximation. Certainly, increasing $N$ (i.e., more sensors), the perfomance will be (statistically) better, but approximations are still approximations: you may check "how much" your approximation is problematic by not generating noise at all, let the algorithm do its job and then plotting the errors (or the ECDF, [Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function), or any other metric that suits your case, e.g. RMS error, with RMS being *Root Mean Square*).

The absolute limit of the performances of *any* estimator is determined by the [Cramer-Rao Lower Bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) (CRLB), which you may be able to calculate under standard assumptions. More information about the CRLB can be found in the literature.